# How to pass data on fetch body without see it in the payload of the request?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Currently I'm working in a request to a service where I'm passing it user and password in the body.
As I understand, this information should be private, however I can see this information in the payload of the request in my browser.

```
const response = await fetch("https://abc.abc.com/", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: {
        "user": "user",
        "password": "123456"
    },
});
```

[image]

Can anyone help me to understand what can I do?

Comment: _"Can anyone help me to understand what can I do?"_ - realize that this is absolutely normal, and that here is of course nothing you can do about it.  _"where I'm passing it user and password in the body"_ - _whose_ username & password? That of the website user, that they themselves entered? They know it already, so there is no need to "hide" it from them in the first place. [...]

Comment: [...] Or those of some external service, that you are trying to authorize against here, with credentials not belonging to the website user? Then this should not happen on the client side to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal, the browser will encrypt the traffic once it's going outside your machine.

below link may be helpful.

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37701/is-encryption-in-https-done-by-the-browser-or-by-the-system